# Why use #define instead of a variable

Tags: c++, c-preprocessor

What is the point of `#define` in C++? I've only seen examples where it's used in place of a "magic number" but I don't see the point in just giving that value to a variable instead.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Mostly stylistic these days.  When C was young, there was no such thing as a const variable.  So if you used a variable instead of a `#define`, you had no guarantee that somebody somewhere wouldn't change the value of it, causing havoc throughout your program.

In the old days, FORTRAN passed even constants to subroutines by reference, and it was possible (and headache inducing) to change the value of a constant like '2' to be something different.  One time, this happened in a program I was working on, and the only hint we had that something was wrong was we'd get an ABEND (abnormal end) when the program hit the `STOP 999` that was supposed to end it normally.

Comment: @farhangdon "Mostly stylistic these days." is the answer to the question.  Basically, use it if your style allows it.  [supercheetah's](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6005009/641833) answer is better.

Comment: Mostly stylistic these days? Nope. Better use defines to avoid a constant that consumes memory especially important when programming microcontrollers with limited resources availabe.

Answer (score 162):

The `#define` is part of the preprocessor language for C and C++.  When they're used in code, the compiler just replaces the `#define` statement with what ever you want.  For example, if you're sick of writing `for (int i=0; i<=10; i++)` all the time, you can do the following:

```
#define fori10 for (int i=0; i<=10; i++)

// some code...

fori10 {
    // do stuff to i
}
```

If you want something more generic, you can create preprocessor macros:

```
#define fori(x) for (int i=0; i<=x; i++)
// the x will be replaced by what ever is put into the parenthesis, such as
// 20 here
fori(20) {
    // do more stuff to i
}
```

It's also very useful for conditional compilation (the other major use for `#define`) if you only want certain code used in some particular build:

```
// compile the following if debugging is turned on and defined
#ifdef DEBUG
// some code
#endif
```

Most compilers will allow you to define a macro from the command line (e.g. `g++ -DDEBUG something.cpp`), but you can also just put a define in your code like so:

```
#define DEBUG
```

Some resources:

1. [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_preprocessor)
2. [C++ specific site](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/preprocessor/)
3. [Documentation on GCC's preprocessor](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/)
4. [Microsoft reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y4skk93w%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)
5. [C specific site](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/cpreprocessor.html) (I don't think it's different from the C++ version though)

Comment: And, by the way, there is no good reason to use a `#define` for a constant in C++ these days.  In fact, it's considered un-C++ or something like that.

Comment: Those who do not fear BOURNEGOL are doomed to repeat it.

Comment: Just as a note, these are all really contrived examples just to show what the preprocessor can do.  I do not recommend anyone actually use any of these.

Comment: That macros better be uppercase, remember MS fiasco of `max` and `min`

Comment: Note that `#define fori(x) for (int i=0; i<=x; i++)` should be written `#define fori(x) for (int i=0; i<=(x); i++)` instead. (Note the additional brackets.) The use of brackets may not be obvious in this example, but something wrong will happen if someone put a bitwise operation in argument x.

Comment: This should have been the chosen answer.

Answer (score 38):

I got in trouble at work one time.  I was accused of using "magic numbers" in array declarations.

Like this:

```
int Marylyn[256], Ann[1024];
```

The company policy was to avoid these magic numbers because, it was explained to me, that these numbers were not portable; that they impeded easy maintenance.  I argued that when I am reading the code, I want to know exactly how big the array is. I lost the argument and so, on a Friday afternoon I replaced the offending "magic numbers" with #defines, like this:

```
 #define TWO_FIFTY_SIX 256
 #define TEN_TWENTY_FOUR 1024

 int Marylyn[TWO_FIFTY_SIX], Ann[TEN_TWENTY_FOUR];
```

On the following Monday afternoon I was called in and accused of having passive defiant tendencies.

Comment: They were very right. `#define MARYLYN_SIZE 256` is what you want.

Comment: The point is to separate the meaning. *Why* is 256 VS 1024 important? It's a 'magic number' because there's no indication of why the value is important. When you know why the value is important, the literal value becomes less important.

Comment: You, sir, are my role model. ;-)

Comment: And then you were fired, right? This was not a very professional way to behave. You were out of line and did not perform the simple task assigned to you. The company policy is correct - just dumping in `256` and `1024` is not maintainable, yet when confronted with this _you decided to make it worse_. If this behaviour continued in my place you'd be **out**.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit What should be the right declaration for that one to make it portable?

Comment: @JAMESBRYANB.Juventud How many Marylyns and Anns should there be? What decision drives that? Name the constants after that decision. e.g. `static constexpr const size_t MAX_HOMES_AVAILABLE = 1024; int Ann[MAX_HOMES_AVAILABLE];`. If the choice is _really_ obvious and localised then using 1024 directly isn't _too_ bad, but doing what Harpee did is just trolling.

Comment: @JAMESBRYANB.Juventud Note that this doesn't have much to do with portability

Comment: Ahh. Ok. That word "trolling" word makes me realize faster. The way he used the naming convention is really bad and hard to maintain. If someone will change the `#define TWO_FIFTY_SIX 256` to `#define TWO_FIFTY_SIX 258`, this code is trolling.

Comment: @Lightness In my company we define ZERO, ONE, TWO, etc. They also come in int, unsigned int, double, float types. Useless practice.

Comment: @jinawee Lol sorry to hear that

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit this is such an annoying way to respond to a funny anecdote that it actually made me mad. "at MY place. . ." shut up you fucking dweeb

Comment: Assuming this passed the review process, I swear in 5 years when they need to double the size you will find those two lines in the code:
    `#define TWO_FIFTY_SIX 512`
    `#define TEN_TWENTY_FOUR 2048`

Answer (score 8):

`#define` can accomplish some jobs that normal C++ cannot, like guarding headers and other tasks. However, it definitely should not be used as a magic number- a static const should be used instead.

Answer (score 7):

C didn't use to have consts, so #defines were the only way of providing constant values. Both C and C++ do have them now, so there is no point in using them, except when they are going to be tested with #ifdef/ifndef.

Comment: They are still handy if you are using templates, you need to know the value in compile-time.

Comment: @Erbureth consts are known at compile time.

Comment: @Erbureth: I believe const values at namespace scope have internal linkage by default, so you are also not using a global variable.  That may only apply to integral constants, though.

Comment: And had I read the comments further down the page, I'd have seen that this point has already been made. Oh well.

Answer (score 4):

Most common use (other than to declare constants) is an [include guard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard).

Answer (score 1):

Define is evaluated before compilation by the pre-processor, while variables are referenced at run-time. This means you control how your application is built (not how it runs)

Here are a couple examples that use define which cannot be replaced by a variable:

1. #define min(i, j) (((i) < (j)) ? (i) : (j))
   note this is evaluated by the pre-processor, not during runtime
2. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8fskxacy.aspx

Comment: The define can easily be replaced by an inline function.

Comment: That define is "expanded" by the pre-processor into a c expression which may or may not be evaluated at compile time. eg min(1,2) vs min(a,b) where a and b are variables.

Comment: @Bo Persson: a template function is needed, inline or not, since it should work on all types.

Answer (score 0):

The `#define` allows you to establish a value in a header that would otherwise compile to size-greater-than-zero.  Your headers should not compile to size-greater-than-zero.

```
// File:  MyFile.h

// This header will compile to size-zero.
#define TAX_RATE 0.625

// NO:  static const double TAX_RATE = 0.625;
// NO:  extern const double TAX_RATE;  // WHAT IS THE VALUE?
```

EDIT:  As Neil points out in the comment to this post, the explicit definition-with-value in the header would work for C++, but not C.

Comment: Um, wrong. `const double TAX_RATE = 0.625`. consts have translation unit scope by default.

Comment: In C constants have external linkage and thus should be defined in .c files.  In C++ they have internal linkage and thus could be defined in header.  So, agree with @Neil if C++ and not C.  (The question relates to magic numbers in header, so I disagree with other tangents for #define as used for include guards or any non-magic-number discussion.)