# Alternatives to using "#define" in C++? Why is it frowned upon?

Tags: c++, coding-style, global-variables, c-preprocessor

I have been developing C++ for less than a year, but in that time, I have heard multiple people talk about how horrible `#define` is. Now, I realize that it is interpreted by the preprocessor instead of the compiler, and thus, cannot be debugged, but is this really that bad?

Here is an example (untested code, but you get the general idea):

```
#define VERSION "1.2"

#include <string>

class Foo {
  public:
    string getVersion() {return "The current version is "+VERSION;}
};
```

1. Why is this this code bad?
2. Is there an alternative to using `#define`?

Comment: The inverse of this question: [Why use #define instead of a variable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6004963/why-use-define-instead-of-a-variable)

Comment: `define`s are tricky constructs and can be easily mis-used or abused.  but just like `goto` they can be very useful.

Comment: possible duplicate of [static const vs #define](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1637332/static-const-vs-define), in particular this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3835772/61574) should be enough.

Comment: I doubt that this code compiles. Without the `+` it would, but as is ? Nope.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> Why is this this code bad?

Because VERSION can be overwritten and the compiler won't tell you.

> Is there an alternative to using #define?

```
const char * VERSION = "1.2";
```

or

```
const std::string VERSION = "1.2";
```

Comment: Actually, the compiler likely *will* tell you when you redefine a macro. Even without any warning options, gcc will warn you with "warning: "FOO" redefined... note: this is the location of the previous definition". And it will do that only if the values are different, so you don't get useless warnings.

Comment: Does a const have the same scope as a `#define`? I guess a `#define` doesn't really have a scope - it can go anywhere. Can a const be used anywhere as well?

Comment: @Joel: One of the biggest advantages of `const x` over `#define` is that it is scoped.

Comment: @Joel: No, it is scoped.  That's usually seen as an advantage.  Do you have a case in mind where it's not?

Comment: In my example, if I replaced my define with a const, would the const be in the global scope? Does this mean that I could use the const anywhere in the file?

Comment: The negative effects of #define in fact depend a lot on whether it's in a header file, or in a source file that is compiled separately. In a source file, you can afford to use much shorter identifiers, including macro names, without risk of conflict, because you see all the code. This also won't collide with the headers you include assuming you always use more specific identifiers in headers (e.g. prefixing them).

Comment: @AmbrozBizjak: the problem is on the other direction, the compiler (the preprocessor actually) will replace VERSION with the string *everywhere*, regardless of context.

Answer (score 11):

The real problem is that defines are handled by a different tool from the rest of the language (the preprocessor). As a consequence, the compiler doesn’t know about it, and cannot help you when something goes wrong – such as reuse of a preprocessor name.

Consider the case of `max` which is sometimes implemented as a macro. As a consequence, you cannot use the identifier `max` anywhere in your code. *Anywhere*. But the compiler won’t tell you. Instead, your code will go horribly wrong and you have no idea why.

Now, with some care this problem can be minimised (if not completely eliminated). But for most uses of `#define` there are better alternatives anyway so the cost/benefit calculation becomes skewed: slight disadvantage for *no* benefit whatsoever. Why use a defective feature when it offers no advantage?

So here is a very simple diagram:

1. Need a constant? Use a constant (not a define)
2. Need a function? Use a function (not a define)
3. Need something that cannot be modelled using a constant or a function? Use a define, but do it properly.

Doing it “properly” is an art in itself but there are a few easy guidelines:

1. Use a unique name. All capitals, always prefixed by a unique library identifier. `max`? Out. `VERSION`? Out. Instead, use `MY_COOL_LIBRARY_MAX` and `MY_COOL_LIBRARY_VERSION`. For instance, Boost libraries, big users of macros, always use macros starting with `BOOST_<LIBRARY_NAME>_`.
2. Beware of evaluation. In effect, a parameter in a macro is just text that is replaced. As a consequence, `#define MY_LIB_MULTIPLY(x) x * x` is broken: it could be used as `MY_LIB_MULTIPLY(2 + 5)`, resulting in `2 + 5 * 2 + 5`. Not what we wanted. To guard against this, *always* parenhesise *all* uses of the arguments (unless you know *exactly* what you’re doing – spoiler: you probably don’t; even experts get this wrong alarmingly often).

   The correct version of this macro would be:

   ```
    #define MY_LIB_MULTIPLY(x) ((x) * (x))
   ```

But there are *still* plenty of ways of getting macros horribly wrong, and, to reiterate, the compiler won’t help you here.

Answer (score 5):

`#define` isn't inherently bad, it's just easy to abuse. For something like a version string it works fine, although a `const char*` would be better, but many programmers use it for much more than that. Using `#define` as a typedef for example is silly when, in most cases, a typedef would be better. So there's nothing wrong with `#define` statements, and some things can't be done without them. They have to be evaluated on a case by case basis. If you can figure out a way to solve a problem without using the preprocessor, you should do it.

Answer (score 2):

I would not use `#define` to define a constant use `static` keyword or better yet 
`const int kMajorVer = 1;`
`const int kMinorVer = 2;`
OR
`const std::string kVersion = "1.2";`

Herb sutter has an excellent article here detailing why `#define` is bad and lists some examples where there is really no other way to achieve the same thing: http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/032.htm.

Basically like with many things its fine so long as you use it correctly but it is easy to abuse and macro errors are particularly cryptic and a bugger to debug.

I personally use them for conditional debug code and also variant data representations, which is detailed at the end of the sutter article.

Answer (score 1):

In general the preprocessor is bad because it creates a two pass compilation process that is unsafe, creates difficult to decode error messages and can lead to hard-to-read code.  You should not use it if possible:

```
const char* VERSION = "1.2"
```

However there are cases where it is impossible to do what you want to do without the preprocessor:

```
#define Log(x) cout << #x << " = " << (x) << endl;
```

Comment: Compilation in C++ actually takes way more than two passes.

Comment: I do not know what you mean by “logical passes”. Or rather, I don’t see how that would be inherently unsafe.

Comment: Consider (A) the original code, (B) the preprocessed intermediate form of the code; and (C) the annotated parse tree.  The two "logical passes" I am referring to are preprocessing `A->B` and compilation `B->C`.

Comment: Yes, that’s what I thought. Why is that inherently unsafe? Are you referring to the fact that `C` cannot contain annotations from `A` since these are lost in the transition `A->B`? This isn’t an inherent problem, just one with current implementations. Clang in fact handles this just fine (as in, the annotated parse tree contains all information from the unpreprocessed source), and as far as I know there are efforts underway to make GCC also handle this.

Comment: It is deeper than that - by specification they are logically separated - the preprocessor resolves all its potentially (turing complete) complex changes on the source, and then the result is compiled (again).  No matter how many compiler/ide features you throw at that, it is never going to be as simple to see what is going on as for example preprocessor-free Java.